# Microsoft Speech Recognition - numbers + navigation

Tags: grammar, dictation, microsoft-speech-platform

I am writing a data entry program that mostly uses C&C via a grammar XML file, but in some cases I need to dictation. When I am in C&C mode, in addition to the list of values, I also include navigation commands (like GO UP, GO DOWN etc) and after recognition, I carry out the right action. All is good there.

But in Dictation mode, recognizing these "commands" is much less successful (as there is no limited list of words).

Questions:

1. I need to use the Dictation because I want to enter numbers. Is there a way to create a C&C grammar file that only limits the list of words to numbers?
2. If there is such solution, I will still need to include my navigation words/commands.
3. If there is no such solution, is there a way to force the dictation to assign higher probabilities to certain "words" the engine hears?